# Qt does not name a type

Tags: qt

Хочу сделать кнопку логаута из приложения как лучше это сделать.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "authdialog.h"
AuthDialog w;
w.show(); //окно авторизации
```

**authdialog.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
MainWindow *win;
бла бла бла
if (ui->loginLineEdit->text() == user)
{
               isAuth(user);
               win = new MainWindow();
               win->setUserOnline(user);
               win->show(); //открываю главное окно программы
               this->close();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "authdialog.h"
AuthDialog *newauth;

        //кнопка логаута по нажатию должно закрытся гласное окно(mainwindow)
        //и открыться authdialog
      void MainWindow::on_logoutPushButton_clicked()
        {
            this->close();
            newauth = new AuthDialog;
            newauth->show();    
        }
```

получаю ошибку

```
mainwindow.h ошибка: 'AuthDialog' does not name a type
     AuthDialog *newauth;
     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
//#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include <QCalendarWidget>
#include <QSqlRelationalDelegate>

#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QRect>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QAction>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextCharFormat>

#include "crmmodel.h"
#include "neworder.h"
#include "delorderdialog.h"
#include "workers.h"
#include "discounts.h"
#include "checkboxdelegate.h"
//#include "comboboxstatusdelegate.h"
#include "phonenumberdelegate.h"
#include "salarydelegate.h"
#include "about.h"
#include "history.h"
#include "buttondelegate.h"
#include "loggingcategories.h"
#include "movetocenter.h"
#include "crmusers.h"
//#include "crmuserdelegate.h"
#include "uploadfileform.h"
//#include "authdialog.h"
#include "contactsform.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    CRMModel *model;
    void setUserOnline(QString user); //получаем из окна авторизации кто залогинелся

private slots:



    void on_addOrderButton_clicked();

    void on_delButton_clicked();

    void orderAccepted();
    void orderCancled();

//    void slotDelOrder();


    void on_calendarWidget_clicked(const QDate &date = QDate::currentDate()); //сколько заказов на выбранный день, по умолчанию ткущий день
    void on_actionAdd_worker_triggered();
    void on_editOrderPushButton_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void on_actionAdd_order_triggered();
    void on_actionExit_triggered();
    void slot_comboWorkersBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1);

    //void on_todayPushButton_clicked();

    void on_todayPushButton_clicked();
    void on_actionAddDiscount_triggered();
    void on_actionInfo_triggered();

//    void moveToCenter(QWidget& widget); //перегрузка функций
//    void moveToCenter(QWidget* widget);//отцентровка открывающихся окон

    void setUserLogout();
    void whoOnline();
    void showOrdersForToday();


    void on_logoutPushButton_clicked();

    void on_actionLogout_triggered();


    void on_lastOrdersPushButton_clicked();

    void on_lastCancelOrdersPushButton_clicked();

    void slotRightClickMenuRequested(QPoint pos); //меню по правой кнопки крысы


    void on_actionHistoryLog_triggered();

    void on_actionCRMusers_triggered();

    void uploadFile();
    void startUpload(int ID,QString NAME);


    void on_b1_clicked();
    void on_b2_clicked();
    void on_b3_clicked();
    void on_b4_clicked();
    void on_b5_clicked();
    void on_b6_clicked();
    void on_b7_clicked();
    void on_b8_clicked();
    void on_b9_clicked();
    void on_b0_clicked();
    void on_bzvezda_clicked();
    void on_breshotka_clicked();



    void on_delPhoneCharPushButton_clicked();

    void on_actionContacts_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    newOrder *new_o;
    delOrderDialog *del_o;
    workers *workers_window;
    discounts *discounts_window;
    about *about_window;
    history *history_window;
    CRMusers *crmusers_window;

    QString clickedDay;
    int typeIndex;
  //  QSqlQuery *todayOrdersQuery;
    QSqlQuery *currentDayTotalOrdersQuery;

    QString userOnline; //сюда переписываем кто сейчас онлайн из окна авторизации
    uploadFileForm *uploadFile_window;
  //  AuthDialog *newauth;
    ContactsForm *contacts_window;


protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**authdialog.h**

```
#ifndef AUTHDIALOG_H
#define AUTHDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QDateTime>


#include "mainwindow.h"



namespace Ui {
class AuthDialog;
}

class AuthDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AuthDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AuthDialog();

private slots:
    void on_enterButton_clicked();
    void isAuth(QString user);

private:
    Ui::AuthDialog *ui;

    QSqlDatabase *db;
    QMessageBox *dbMess;
    QSqlQuery *query;
    QMessageBox *nullMess;
    QMessageBox *connMess;
    QMessageBox *enterMess;
    MainWindow *win;


};

#endif // AUTHDIALOG_H
```

Comment: Ошибка же в **mainwindow.h**, его тоже можно прикрепить

Comment: в authdialog подключает mainwindow в котором подключен authdialog. Вот он и тупит. Как это обойти?

Comment: выложить сюда все файлы, в том числе **mainwindow.h** и **authdialog.h**

Comment: они там уже огромные очень https://github.com/89626906891/crm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `mainwindow.h` после всех `#include` добавьте

```
class AuthDialog;
```

Ниже в файле Вы используете указатель на `AuthDialog` (сейчас закомментирован, но ошибка явно была от него) поэтому необходимо чтобы было видно объявление класса. Но включить `authdialog.h` в `mainwindow.h` не получится из-за возникновения циклической зависимости между ними. Решение - [предварительное объявление](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (forward declaration).